# Finding a specific disk automorphism.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

While preparing for a test I am encountering a lot of problems of type:

Find a conformal map from half-plane/unit disk to half-plane/unit disk such that point $z_0$ goes to $w_0$ and derivative of map at point $z_0$ has an argument equal to $\alpha$.

Firstly, what is a reason to give such problems? Are such calculations extensively used in some physics/applied math problems?

Secondly, how to solve such problems? I can try to move a this problem to problem of finding a specific upper halfplane/disk automorhisms and start solving system of equations: $\phi(z_0)=w_0\; \phi'(z_0) = ke^{i\alpha}$ for $\phi$ having a usual disk/halfplane automorphism form.

I had found an answer for disk variant in textbook

[image: answer]

But I don't know how to get this formula, when I tried, calculations got very messy and I could not move forward without constantly making mistakes and involution gets into my way too much. I can sometimes solve a system for a concrete values, but usually I bury myself in calculations. What would be a less computation heavy  approach?

Comment: Assume that $z_0$ and $w_0$ lie inside the unit disk $\mathbb D$. MTs that map $\mathbb D$ to itself and map $a \in \mathbb D$ to $0$ have the form $f_{a, \phi}(z) = e^{i \phi} (z - a)/(1 - \overline a z)$. Consider $f'(a)$ and $(f^{-1})'(0)$ to show that the answer is $f_{w_0, 0}^{-1} \circ f_{z_0, \alpha}$. Note that the formula in the screenshot is not correct in general for complex $z_0$ and $w_0$. The first problem can be solved in the same way (mapping the upper half-plane $\mathbb H$ to $\mathbb D$ and then $\mathbb D$ to $\mathbb H$).

Comment: We can use groups of transformations to turn problems into more "canonical" problems. For this, it is helpful to know how much "control" we have in transforming things. In this case, the problem is essentially showing that Mobius transformations act transitively on the unit tangent bundle of the plane / disk.